# Will L7806 work with NodeMCU?

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I have a [NodeMCU LUA Lolin V3](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1509/1638/files/NodeMCU_Lua_Lolin_V3_Modul_mit_ESP8266_12E_Datenblatt.pdf) with an ESP8266 -12E.

I want to know if I can use an [L7806CV](https://www.mouser.ch/datasheet/2/389/cd00000444-1795274.pdf) votage regulator with it through the VIN pin?

The NodeMCU has an AMS1117 3.3 voltage regulator.

Comment: What does NodeMCU documentation say about VIN pin?

Comment: You should add some links to the datasheets. I cannot find a NodeMCU LUA Lolin V3 with an ESP8366. Maybe a typo?

Comment: Errata - should read ESP8266-12E.

Comment: @Seir: It was a typo. I meant ESP8266.

Answer (score 1):

According to the ["Schematics"](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1509/1638/files/NodeMCU_Lua_Lolin_V3_Schematics.pdf), VIN (5V .. 9V) is tied to the [AMS1117 3.3V](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf). Therefore you're safe to use a [L7806CV](https://www.mouser.ch/datasheet/2/389/cd00000444-1795274.pdf) to provide regulated 6V input voltage.

You have to supply the L7806CV with at least 8V and up to 35V. But for thermal reasons, and depending on the input voltage and current drawn, a power switcher might be the better choice.